# Chain rule multiple variables

Tags: real-analysis

Let $u(x,y)=\ln(x+y)e^{\cos(x+y)}$ and $h(x)=u(x,1+x^3)$. What is $\frac {dh}{dx}$? How do I use the chain rule in this case?

Comment: Let $v(x) = (x,1+x^3)$. Then $h = u\circ v$. What does the chain rule say about the derivative of $(u\circ v)$?

Comment: What would the derivative of $v$ be?

Comment: What is generally the derivative of a function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$? For $v$, we have $n = 1,\; m = 2$, while for $u$ we have $n = 2,\; m = 1$.

Comment: $\frac{dv}{dx}=(1,3x^2)$?

Comment: That's right. Now, what does the chain rule make of the derivative of $u\circ v$? First answer that abstractly, without caring what the concrete $u$ and $v$ are. Just look at the domain and codomain.

Comment: $u'\circ v+ u\circ v'$?

Comment: No. That looks like a product rule, not like a chain rule. You should have a statement of the chain rule in your book or lecture notes. Look it up, and adapt the general formulation to the given dimensions of the domain and codomain of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: $(u'\circ v)v'$?

Comment: That's the chain rule for functions of one real variable, or it could be the chain rule on a more abstract level. Have you something with partial derivatives in it?

Comment: Do you mean something like $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dv}\frac{dv}{dx}$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $v_1(t)=t, v_2(t)=1+t^3$ and $v(t) = (v_1(t),v_2(t))=(t,1+t^3)$ and $h(t)=u(v(t))$
From the chain rule you get:
$$
\frac{dh}{dt}(t)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(v(t))\frac{dv_1}{dt}(t) + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(v(t))\frac{dv_2}{dt}(t)
$$

Since $h(x) = \ln(x+1+x^3)e^{\cos(x+1+x^3)}$ you can compute $h'(x)$ and verify your result.

Comment: But that's substitution and chain rule with one variable. I'd like to see the use of the chain rule with multiple variables

Comment: @RalphBond please see my update